# Why $|H_1(\Sigma,\mathbb{Z}_N)|$ can be interpreted as an 1+1d $\mathbb{Z}_2$ gauge theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, condensation

I am reading the article https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.02407, and I am struggling with the definition of a condensation defect, which is given by
\begin{align}
S(\Sigma)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|H_1(\Sigma,\mathbb{Z}_N)|}}\sum_{\gamma\in H_1(\Sigma,\mathbb{Z}_N)}\eta(\gamma).
\end{align}
Here, $\eta(\gamma)$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_N$ line, i.e. $\eta(\gamma)^N=1$.

As an example, let us consider $N=2$ and $\Sigma$ to be the 2-torus. Then the condensation defect is given by
\begin{align}
S(T^2)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|H_1(T^2,\mathbb{Z}_2)|}}\left(1+\eta(A)+\eta(B)+\eta(A+B)\right)
\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|H_1(T^2,\mathbb{Z}_2)|}}\left(1+\eta(A)+\eta(B)+\eta(A)\eta(B)\right),
\end{align}
where $A$ and $B$ are the non-contractible loops of the torus and I have considered that $\eta(\gamma)$ is a bosonic line, such that $\eta(A+B)=\eta(A)\eta(B)$. If I take these equations and try to calculate the product of two condensation defects I find
\begin{align}
S(\Sigma)\times S(\Sigma)=\frac{4}{\sqrt{|H_1(T^2,\mathbb{Z}_2)|}} S(\Sigma).
\end{align}

However, in the article it is claimed that this fusion coefficient should be an $1+1d \hspace{1mm} \mathbb{Z}_2$ gauge theory, i.e.
\begin{align}
S(\Sigma)\times S(\Sigma)=(1+1d \hspace{1mm} \mathbb{Z}_2 \hspace{1mm} \text{gauge theory})S(\Sigma).
\end{align}

So, if possible I would like to understand the following questions:

1. Given the elements of the cohomology class $H_1(\Sigma,\mathbb{Z}_N)$, how do I find $|H_1(\Sigma,\mathbb{Z}_N)|$ ?
2. If my fusion coeficient is right, how do I interpret this as an $1+1d \hspace{1mm} \mathbb{Z}_2$ gauge theory ?

Answer (score 1):

Your computation is basically correct. $|H_1(\Sigma,Z_N)|$ is the number of elements in the group $H_1(\Sigma,Z_N)$. For example, $|H_1(T^2,Z_2)|=4$. For bosonic defect lines ($\eta(A)\eta(B)=\eta(B)\eta(A)$) and $\Sigma=T^2$,
$$S(T^2)\times S(T^2)= \frac{4}{|H_1(T^2,Z_2)|} S(T^2)=\sqrt{|H_1(T^2,Z_2)|}\; S(T^2).$$
For general $\Sigma$ and bosonic defect lines,
$$S(\Sigma)\times S(\Sigma)= \frac{|H_1(\Sigma,Z_2)|}{|H_1(\Sigma,Z_2)|} S(\Sigma)=\sqrt{|H_1(\Sigma,Z_2)|}\; S(\Sigma).$$
The "$(1+1d\;Z_2\;\textrm{gauge theory})$" is their notation for the partition function of $1+1d\;Z_2\;\textrm{gauge theory}$
$$(1+1d\;Z_2\;\textrm{gauge theory})\equiv \textrm{the partition function for } 1+1d\;Z_2\;\textrm{gauge theory}=\sqrt{|H_1(\Sigma,Z_2)|}.$$
The last equal sign is what claimed by Shu-Heng (under Eq. 4.11). I do not know why.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it already illuminated somethings for me :)